# How do you bring to front a usercontrol added to a canvas in code behind

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls, canvas, z-order

I have a series of usercontrols that are added and removed from a canvas in code behind.  I need to insure that certain ones are forward of others.  How do you set, what used to be the ZOrder in VB6, the order of a user control once it is added to a canvas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Eh, apologies...you'll have to translate this to VB.Net code...as i only code in C# with WPF

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(control, zIndex);
```

[Canvas.SetZIndex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setzindex(VS.95).aspx)

And more info about canvas and the z-index: [Canvas.ZIndex Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.zindex(VS.95).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I posted a solution with code [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453613/how-do-i-bring-an-item-to-the-front-in-wpf/24120993#24120993). this solution is in WPF, so if you want VB, you will have to do a bit of translation.